# No module named 'gspread', ModuleNotFoundError. Problem with import in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, gspread

I seem to have a very common problem although nothing I try works for me:

I have installed Python 3.6.5 for Windows 64 bit and am using Vs Code for editing.

I used Ubuntu to install pip3 and then installed gspread as follows:

```
pip3 install gspread
```

Although `import gspread` gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\Vs Code\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gspread
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'
```

How do I fix this problem to import gspread?

Comment: You might need to check whether you have downloaded the package to the correct python environment (that's if you have downloaded more than one version of python to your computer).

Comment: @MaxCollier how do I check that? I did have previous versions of python on my computer although they have been uninstalled

Comment: I know for example that on windows you can check that pip3 matches the correct python version by comparing whether the directories of `where python` and `where pip` lead to the same folder in cmd (command prompt). However I don't know the ubuntu equivalent sorry.

Comment: Both `where pip3` and `where pip` outputs C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip3.exe and `where python` outputs C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe... Do I need to move pip3 to the same foloder as python?

Comment: How are you running your Python code? Are you sure you have the right interpreter selected in VS Code (check the status bar)? And you can check you have `gspread` installed with `pip3 list`.

Comment: @BrettCannon I had the right interpreter and gspread was listed under `pip3 list`, I ended up downloading the gspread library from GitHub and manually adding it to my Python libraries in `C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib` which worked. So maybe pip3 was installing it to an incorrect location?

Answer (score 0):

you can input, in python console :

```
in[1]: pip install gspread
```

the picture was taken after installation, for demonstration

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please open a new post if you have a question.

Comment: i think it help ..., cause it is one topic in stackoverflow, about bug of import gspread.

Comment: This only shows, that you have the same problem, but not how you fixed it (if you did). An answer has to contain a suggestion on how to resolve the problem or answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @toydarian It is an answer, but not a very good one. So it shouldn't be deleted in the Low Quality posts review queue.

Comment: @10Rep ah, now I see. It wasn't clear for me, that `pip install gspread` is actually the fix/workaround.

Comment: @toydarian Yeah, it can be confusing.